# JavaFX: stage icon crashes when running on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, javafx

I am adding an icon to my stage's window like in Fig 1 (line 7) on Eclipse. Stage will handle a scene that will be forcing it to resize depending on the component inside it (a SIZE*SIZE board actually).

```
public ScreenManager(Stage primaryStage, String name) {
    root = new StackPane();
    scene = new Scene(root);
    stage = primaryStage;
    stage.setTitle(name);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image("res/images/GameIconsSmall.png"));
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    root.setVisible(true);
}
```

Fig 1: [image: Fig 1]

Fig 2: [image: Fig 2]

Fig 3: [image: Fig 3]

Fig 2 is what happens (not every time though but usually) when the stage gets resized through setWidth and setHeight during the program's execution. I would also like to change Java's default desktop icon (Fig 3) to one of my own, independent from the OS.

Comment: For your icons, you need to provide more than one icon. Mac OS and other platforms need different resolutions than only one, for example the one for the desktop icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also inserted `stage.getIcons().add(new Image("res/images/GameIconsSmall.png"));` inside a block of code that changed the stage's width and height. That was crashing the icon. I still haven't been able to to change Java's default desktop icon, though.

Comment: Try add / before res or if res is a resource folder like src the try /images... without res.

Comment: Desktop icon could be changed by correct packaging of the jar. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html